# Setting constraints for dynamic cell

Tags: ios, xcode, uitableview, autolayout, constraints

I'm new to using constraints in my iOS projects, and  trouble setting the right constraints for my dynamic `UITableViewCell`. I've tried every combination I can think of but it either won't dynamically change height, or it gives me warnings about ambiguous layouts.

My first label1 is not supposed to change in height, but the other two are. My current constraints achieve the desired effect, but are giving me the warnings seen under.
[image]

[image]

The warnings go away if I constrain the height of the labels (obviously), but that doesn't solve my problem.

Any suggestions on how to solve this would be appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all you need to set

```
tableView.rowHeight = UITableViewAutomaticDimension
tableView.estimatedRowHeight = 44.0
```

in viewDidLoad of your UITableViewController

Then you need to set constraints from top to bottom of the cell

```
top space to superview
vertical spacing
bottom space to superview
height greater or equal
```

[image]
[image]
[image]

and of course set lines to 0 for every UILabel

Example project is available here https://github.com/MihaelIsaev/SwiftAutoResizableCells

Comment: When following your steps, I run into another problem, the first time the cells are used, it does not dynamically change height, but after scrolling the table view and letting the cells be reused, they look perfect. Any suggestions?

Comment: Are you tried to run my example project? The same problem in my project? I tested it and it works perfectly. Maybe you missed something?

Comment: I could not locate the xib-file for your custom cell in the project, so I could not compare your constraints with mine. Would you please explain where it is, or send me an image of your constraints?

Comment: I just use storyboard, you can find my cell prototype in the Main.storyboard. And you can download whole project, open it in Xcode and run.

Comment: My constraints are the same as yours but the problem remains. Do you have any ideas to a workaround? As previously said, all other cells than the first 5 that are shown are fine. After being reused, the first 5 are also fine.

Comment: Solved it by programmatically scrolling the view so that the cells would reuse without the user knowing, thanks for the help with the constraints!